# append <script> tag in body using jquery nothing working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a another jquery file to body using jquery. all strings are working but script tags doesn't.

I used this:

1.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var string = '<script src="bootstrap.min.js">';
    //alert(string);
$("<script"+ " src"+"\="+ "bootstrap.min.js"+" type"+"="+"text\/javascript"+"></script>").appendTo($("body"));

    });
```

2. `$("body").append($("<script>", {  src : "bootstrap.min.js",  type : "text/javascript" }));`

nothing works.

i have tried dual slashes and above scripts nothing happening and a normal string works such as 'this is a line', but not script tag

Comment: try the second one will full path instead of `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$.getScript()`

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of double and single quotes to not escape quotes

```
$('body').append('<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>');
```